# Default number of reducers for Spark SQL query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a query in SparkSQL which involves shuffle. The number of partitions in the Dataframe is theoretically unlimited (practically 10s of thousands of partitions).

I ran into the 'Too many open files' Exception when I ran the query and came up with the following answer from [Spark's mailing list](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/quot-Too-many-open-files-quot-exception-on-reduceByKey-td2462.html) which basically states that:

> In general if a node in your cluster has C assigned cores and you run a job with X reducers then Spark will open C*X files in parallel and start writing.

Until now every time I stumbled upon this error I increased the number of open files in `limits.conf` and I wonder when this will end? from the Spark UI I can see that the shuffle procedure has 200 partitions by default.

What is the number of reducers which run when I run the query? is it 200 for the shuffle and >10K for the calculation? it is a predefined value?

Comment: What's the query? Is this `groupBy` or something else? Can you add a screenshot of the Spark job(s) for the query in question? There's no direct notion of reducers as in Hadoop MapReduce.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski the query means: Dataset<Row> sqlResult = sqlContext.sql(query); sqlResult.collect(); nothing else, only the computation of the filter-sort itself

Comment: What's `query` that you pass to `sqlContext.sql`? What's the version of Spark?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Spark version is 2.1.0, what is the effect of the query over the number of reducers? is there any maximum? example for query: 'select distinct sourceip, destinationport from table where destinationport=80'